# Create N x 2 array from N x 1 array-Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 1D array (say A) of size N (i.e N x 1; N-rows, 1 Column). Now I want to create an array of size N x 2 (N-rows, 2-columns) with the array A as one column and the other column with a same element (0 in the given example below).

> For e.g If

```
A =[1;2;3;4;5];
```

> I'd like to create a matrix B which is

```
B=[0 1; 0 2; 0 3; 0 4; 0 5]
```

How do I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can initialize `B` to be an `Nx2` array of all zeros and then assign the second column to the values in `A`.

```
A = [1;2;3;4;5];

B = zeros(numel(A), 2);
B(:,2) = A;

%   0   1 
%   0   2     
%   0   3     
%   0   4     
%   0   5
```

If you actually just want zeros in that first column,  you don't even have to initialize `B` as MATLAB will automatically fill in the unknown values with 0.

```
% Make sure B isn't already assigned to something
clear B

% Assign the second column of uninitialized variable B to be equal to A
B(:,2) = A;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also abuse [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for a one-liner -

```
bsxfun(@times,[0,1],A)
```

Or matrix-multiplication for that implicit expansion -

```
A*[0,1]
```

Comment: Love these approaches (+1)

Comment: @Divakar: I don't understand in this approach what should I do to get a value other than zero? For e.g a column containing 22 along with A.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar You could do `bsxfun(@plus,A*[0,1],[22,0])`. But for efficiency, I would suggest using `@Suever's answer` by initializing with `B = 22*ones(numel(A), 2);` and then `B(:,2) = A;`. Or just concatenate : `B = [22*ones(numel(A),1) A]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
B=[zeros(length(A),1) A]
```